# rewrite url issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'd like to know why the following htaccess file produces a 500 error:

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 500 "Your_Server_Is_Not_Compatible: Apache does not have mod_rewrite loaded. Please check your Apache setup."
    RedirectMatch 302 .* index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ versions/0/1/$1

</IfModule>
```

Thanks thanks in advance

Comment: So i want any file to be redirected to its equivalent in the folder /versions/0/1, for ex, index.php => versions/0/1/index.php, etc...

Comment: i did that, and no error shows on the log

Comment: i don't have access to the access.log file unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a 500 error because you're causing the server to enter an infinite loop (which it gets angry about, and throws an error to stop).

This is because of your `RewriteRule`, which will always match:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ versions/0/1/$1
```

`^(.*)$` matches the value `versions/0/1/`, so after you perform the initial rewrite, the rule set is re-evaluated and creates a cycle that looks like this:

```
versions/0/1/something
versions/0/1/versions/0/1/something
versions/0/1/versions/0/1/versions/0/1/something
```

..and so on.

You should condition your `RewriteRule` to prevent the looping, perhaps as follows:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/versions
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ versions/0/1/$1
```

Also, your `ErrorDocument 500` statement doesn't make much sense, as you will never generate a 500 error *because* you don't have `mod_rewrite` enabled, since you've surrounded the relevant `mod_rewrite` directives with `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`.

Comment: You the man, Tim! Right on the money! How dumb I was not to think about that! Well, that's why community-powered web rocks!

Comment: BTW, this is what I came up with in case it helps

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine on
 
 # dev
   # hack to avoid infinite loop
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/versions/
   # redirects to dev
   RewriteRule ^dev/(.+) versions/0/1/$1 [L]
 
 # stable
   # hack to avoid infinite loop
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/versions/
   # redirects to stable
   RewriteRule ^(.+) versions/0/0/$1

</IfModule>